# User-defined TypeGuard stopped working when upgrading from 4.9.5 to 5.1.6

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have an enum NotificationType that lists the types of notifications. And a notification data model which is represented by the NotificationModel interface

```
 enum NotificationType {
  UsersReportGenerationFinished = 'UsersReportGenerationFinished',
  GroupsReportGenerationFinished = 'GroupsReportGenerationFinished',
}

   type Data<T extends NotificationType> = T extends NotificationType.UsersReportGenerationFinished
    ? UsersGenerationFinishedModel
    : T extends NotificationType.GroupsReportGenerationFinished
    ? GroupsGenerationFinishedModel
    : never;

   interface NotificationModel<T extends NotificationType = NotificationType> {
    dataType: NotificationType;
    data: Data<T>;
  }
```

I also have a user defined type guard:

```
 function isNotificationOfType<T extends NotificationType>(
  serviceNotification: NotificationModel,
  NotificationType: T
): serviceNotification is NotificationModel<T> {
  return serviceNotification.dataType === NotificationType;
}
```

The problem is that TypeScript has stopped correctly determining the type for the data property from the NotificationModel, which is why it can't see the taskId property, which is inside the data object for this type.

I tried to read the changelog between 4.9.5 and 5.1.6 and found nothing to help me find an answer to the problem.

I am attaching a link to [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6#code/AQUwdgrgtsDKICcBuBLAxiAcgewC4oDN0BDfbMAFQE8AHEYAbwChhgBVAZ0Q4CUQbsCXAHFwiUinIAxFGBQcAFiAAmwALzAA5J258BQ0WHFkwMuYpWaANC2DCE2CDV79BIsQgnTZ8pao2a9o7Oem6GxpKmPhbK1kwAvkxMIAAe+rjAYMRQIBw0xBhwiKgYOPhEaF5gALLYyiAANoy2qenAuLT0ACKkxAA8FKApuODKHEXI6Fh4hCQm1HQAfOrAg6kjYGMTJdPlc5ELIAB0Oggu6eGeJma+KrasAPzsXGeXVTcxtfUN98AAXKshhstvBJqUZhUqocjkEnOcwh53tE-L8nrDnG9rsiVF9Gr8AUYkIgANxJVitNzAWQjBAEAr0ABqKBAAHcBkDRuNQTsyrNKvNOituVNeZCBUtmqxWMpeocAcLwXt+QdOqSpcAZbhiACelqBos1cBEokWmlKdTEHTCqcOJjIh8-Limsx1VqOABrACSygJ0AARiTfghXEIKCAoDQGqQsNkQACOLgELIAOaG1jB9Jy4AJpNgVO-eSwCBoDAcDgAv3YbANEDEMBp4BEGsABVICnjiZTwAAPpkIA0GoaTeSzUIqWAaVb6OjbYiseZHXVGpKpRm3N7fVAAwgG2vQ+HI9GN32t4H1XvcABhQTBqMmY+QU87gscIsl3Ll4CV6u1+u2E0sAQEBgGgJhUq+xQihC+zkAA8gQhzsusnLbFBSpQp0iwABS2C8PLQcq5DypBip8lUTpHEyrI2KweFoWR4pxqsTAAJTxiRuwMZE4GoaRYqRBRVFshQywusAwa4BACBgNmHGijBYBHJqxCHOoagaHRfEKYcpImkBIFgSMCZYZpnH8eQn4KmZCmCcybJWfJhGUJhADaAC6VjiSGuDepZIC4H0j7bosbHAEg2AoKoYm0XJBFVBwRxNjSWEmbF6EmMRYLWU5tmsn0DlxYxIXqMsL4FelkTwYcqVZY5VSeeVXHkNCNqhAYc72tiygscAABkvVeekvlHAoxAcDV+EVeQSm9Ecbpet19wsQkTBAA), the code with version 5.1.6 and above does not work, however with version 4.9.5 everything works fine.

In the above code I have abstractly reproduced the problem inside a function named test.

Comment: Denis, that is an excellent problem.  I don’t have a solution, but I do have a stripped-down [version of the original problem](https://shorturl.at/aqwKR), which may help you to reason about it.